# Referencing callee when refactoring in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

Let there be a method like this:

```
public int a() {
   return 1 + b();
}
```

Is it possible to apply the "Introduce parameter" refactoring in eclipse on the expression `b()` such that the caller actually calls the method b on the callee? Like this:

```
o.a()         // old
o.a( o.b() )  // new
```

When I do it, it basically copy&pastes the string "b()" into the call which doesn't make sense of cause because this method is on the callee, not the caller. But maybe you know a trick?

Or, alternatively, is it possible to use the "Change Method Signature" refactoring and use an expression in the default value which references the callee? So that I could create a new parameter on `a()` and let it have a default value of something like `${this}.b()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this indirectly:

1. Introduce Indirection on `o.a()` (call it `a_tmp`)
2. Refactor `a_tmp` from `return o.a()` to `return o.a(o.b())`
3. Inline `a_tmp`

Comment: I put the indirection in the same class as `a()` and it works perfectly!